# How can use memory BIO's pointer for reading and writing?

Tags: pointers, openssl, read-write

First  I create Memory BIO like this

```
BIO *mem = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
BIO_puts(mem, "Hello World\n");
```

and get the pointer like this

```
BUF_MEM *bptr;
BIO_get_mem_ptr(mem, &bptr);
```

My doubt is how can I write and read by using **bptr** pointer?
Is this possible..?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49036152/correct-way-to-write-and-read-a-null-terminated-string-with-an-openssl-memory-bi

Answer (score 1):

Definition of BUF_MEM is as follows:

```
typedef struct buf_mem_st BUF_MEM;
struct buf_mem_st
{
size_t length;  /* current number of bytes */
char *data;
size_t max; /* size of buffer */
};
```

You can see it is basically a wrapper over char * buffer. You can access data and perform read and write operations (while maintaining constraint of length and max of the structure).