# Correct way to write and read a null-terminated string with an OpenSSL memory BIO

Tags: c, openssl

If you execute the following example (almost entirely based on the official https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/crypto/BIO_s_mem.html#EXAMPLE):

```
#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <openssl/buffer.h>

int main() {
    BIO *mem = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
    BIO_puts(mem, "Hello World\n");

    BUF_MEM *bptr;
    BIO_get_mem_ptr(mem, &bptr);
    BIO_set_close(mem, BIO_NOCLOSE); /* So BIO_free() leaves BUF_MEM alone */
    BIO_free(mem);

    printf("%s", bptr->data);

    BUF_MEM_free(bptr);
    return 0;
}
```

It just *might* work as expected depending on the possibility that the uninialised `char` in the underlying memory buffer after the `\n` is `\000` by chance and this can be confirmed with the Valgrind report:

```
==17122== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==17122==    at 0x52CCCC0: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1632)
==17122==    by 0x52D3898: printf (printf.c:33)
==17122==    by 0x4008CC: main (test1.c:13)
==17122==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==17122==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==17122==    by 0x4E9CE77: CRYPTO_malloc (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
==17122==    by 0x4F4A4B3: BUF_MEM_grow_clean (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
==17122==    by 0x4F4BBDD: mem_write (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
==17122==    by 0x4F4AC8E: BIO_puts (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
==17122==    by 0x40086E: main (test1.c:6)
```

Anyway, I have seen that this happened because the `BIO_puts` didn't write a null-terminated string into the memory BIO, even when https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/crypto/BIO_puts.html says:

> BIO_puts() attempts to write a null terminated string buf to BIO b.

So my question is what is the right way to write and read a null-terminated string with an OpenSSL memory BIO.

Additionally, ¿using this API in this way couldn't leak sensitive data?.

Note I'm using OpenSSL `1.0.2g`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

BIO_puts writes all the data in a string up until the NUL terminator - but it does not include the NUL terminator itself. Instead use BIO_write():

```
const char *mystr = "Hello World\n";

BIO_write(mem, mystr, strlen(mystr) + 1);
```

Or alternatively:

```
BIO_puts(mem, "Hello World\n");
BIO_write(mem, "", 1);
```

Comment: Maybe OpenSSL documentation should improve the following sentence:  _"BIO_puts() attempts to write a null terminated string buf to BIO b."_ in https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/crypto/BIO_puts.html#DESCRIPTION to clarify that even when it requires the input of a null-terminated string it won't write a null-terminated string.